# E-commerce public JSON URLs

Tags: web-scraping, shopify

Some of the Shopify APIs are exposed and can be used to pull data from random e-commerce sites

https://shopname.myshopify.com/products.json

Is this something found with other e-commerce platforms like Magento etc.

I am trying to recreate my method for scraping Shopify stores into other platforms